# Upgrading from Azure Storage SDK v6.0.0.0 to v12.4.2 for .NET Framework

Tags: .net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, .net-standard, azure-storage-queues

I have a service that is referring to Azure SDK 3.0 in turn using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll` of version 6.0.0.0. The service is built on .NET Framework and now when I want to to upgrade the Azure Storage SDK(Blobs, Common and Queues) to version 12.4.2, the library is published in .NET Standard

Per my understanding, I can't refer a .NET Standard library in a .NET Framework Library. I searched all over the internet but I couldn't find any way other than migrating my whole service to .NET Core.NET Standard.

Is there any other way to upgrade the latest version of Azure Storage SDKs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any other way to upgrade the latest version of Azure Storage SDKs?

Direct upgrade from version 6 to 12 is not possible as SDK version 12 is actually quite different than older versions (9 or below).

Firstly, now the SDK is split in many SDKs and there are different SDKs for each service (Blobs, Files and Queues). Thus you would need to reference different Nuget packages in your source code.

Secondly, there have been many breaking changes in the SDKs thus simply referencing the Nuget packages for version 12 is just not sufficient. You will need to rewrite the code unfortunately.